# How to make view config inside Express.js outside route?

Tags: node.js, express

I've got json layout config structure, something like:

```
var ActionConfig = {
  '/': {
    'javascripts': [
      '/file1.js',
      '/file2.js'    
    ],
    'styles': [
      '/style.css'
    ],
    'title': 'Main Page Title',
    'description': 'Page Description'
  },
  '/user/': {
    'styles': [
      '/styleForUserList.css'
    ],
    'title': 'User list'
  },
  '/user/:id': {
    'styles': [
      '/styleForUser.css'
    ],
    'title': 'User detail'
  }
};
```

In this object, first level labels are route paths further handled by router. I want to make `res.locals.viewConfig = ActionConfig[req.route.path];` which would be send specific config based on action, but I can't do it before my: `app.use('/', routes);` because there is no route yet. I can't do it after this line, because routes are already handled here. I don't want to put this line in every router action.

Comment: You can just do it before, adding `app.use('*', function() {..` etc.

Comment: before there is no req.route.path variable - therefore I can't distinguish my config by action

Comment: Sure, if for some reason you can't do it in the routes, and not after, the only option left would be before. `app.use('*', function(req, res, next) { var url = req.originalUrl ...  });`